# sendmail error in CGI Perl

Tags: perl, cgi, sendmail

Hi anyone knows about CGI? I am having a problem in posting form details in CGI. 
This will be the error that displays:

Software error:

```
syntax error at ./init.cgi line 90, near "$cf"
Compilation failed in require at /home/delphis/html/cust/campaign/postmail.cgi line 17, <DATA> line 855. For help, please send mail to the webmaster (sample@sample.com), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.
```

The line that executed :
.init.cgi

```
     # sjis 
     $cf{kcode} = '';

     # ‘—Mæƒ[ƒ‹ƒAƒhƒŒƒX
     $cf{mailto} = '';

     # sendmail‚ÌƒpƒXyƒT[ƒoƒpƒXz
     # ¨ ƒvƒƒoƒCƒ_‚ÌŽw’è‚ðŠm”F‚Ì‚±‚Æ
     $cf{sendmail} = '/usr/sbin/sendmail'

     # sendmail‚Ö‚Ì-fƒRƒ}ƒ“ƒhiƒvƒƒoƒCƒ_‚ÌŽd—lŠm”Fj
     # 0=no 1=yes
     $cf{send_fcmd} = 0;
```

line90:  `$cf{send_fcmd} = 0;`

postmail.cgi

```
# Ý’èƒtƒ@ƒCƒ‹”FŽ¯
require "./init.cgi";
my %cf = init();
```

line 17 `require "./init.cgi";`

I don't think this is the server error or in the syntax on how to process the sendmail in CGI / PERL

Answer (score 3):

You are missing ; in the end of the line:

```
$cf{sendmail} = '/usr/sbin/sendmail'
```